# First error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: apex

While I am updating the list of user record's isActive flag to false, I am getting an error.

> Update failed. First exception on row 1 with id <User_is>; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: <user_id>: [] Class..: line <>, column <>"

```apex
List<User> userList = [SELECT Id, isActive FROM User WHERE AccountId = :userAccId];
for(User u : userList){
    u.IsActive = false;
}
update userList;
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to clarify what kind of user is triggering the action.  Is it a community user who triggers the Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY means that the user who is trying to make the update does not have access to a related element that is required for the record to be updated and saved in SFDC.

So basically make sure that:
1-You don't update a record that does not exist,
2-You don't update object field that is build-in/read-only,
3-You perform the action using the user who does not have the right access to modify the object

You can check the object access for the profile:-

Go to setup  profile  object setting and select the object that you are trying to update  edit  enable edit or modify all option.

[image]

Or you can check that user having what type of access on that record by using DML:-
List lstUserRecordAccess = [SELECT RecordId,MaxAccessLevel,HasAllAccess,   HasEditAccess, HasReadAccess, HasTransferAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = 'Enter user id ' AND RecordId = ' Enter record id'];